# Meshlab 'close holes' Max size

Tags: meshlab

What measurement unit does the `MeshLab close holes` function need?

`Meshlab -> Filters -> Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction -> Close Holes`

What is `Max size to be closed = 30`? `30` what? What unit is the default value please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the hole is expressed as number of edges of the boundary of the hole.